# Creación de componente en Reactjs con ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-2015

Por ejemplo la creación de este componente en Reactjs como sería con EcmaScript6?

```
var HelloWorldComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div className="message">Hello World! </div>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así seria

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="message">Hello World! </div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Aquí **debes** tener en cuenta como será la implementación de tu componente.

El ejemplo que describes es lo que se conoce en react como un componente  ***de presentación*** por lo que puedes usar una clase con un constructor solamente. Ni siquiera tienes que heredar de `React.Component`

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorldComponent {
  constructor() {
    return <div className="message">Hello World! </div>;
  }
}

export default HelloWorldComponent;
```

Esto se traduce a

```
var HelloWorldComponent = function() {
    return <div className="message">Hello World! </div>;
}
```

Lo cual es una sintáxis soportada por react

Hay una sintáxis aún mas simple que es usando arrow functions

```
var HelloWorldComponent = () =>  {
    return <div className="message">Hello World! </div>;
};

export default HelloWorldComponent;
```

Siempre queda la opción tradicional

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="message">Hello World! </div>;
    }
}

export default HelloWorldComponent;
```

Lo cual básicamente hace lo mismo que todo lo anterior pero con más código y más difícil de leer.

En caso que sea un componente ***contenedor*** es importante que entiendas que `React.createClass` no se comporta exactamente igual que `extends React.Component`. En este caso debes llamar a `super(props)` en el constructor y ya no necesitas llamar a `componentWillMount` pues el constructor es el encargado de este paso.

```
import React from 'react';
import Foo from './Foo'
import Bar from './Bar'

class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Aquí pones todo lo que usualmente pondrías en componentWillMount
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Foo />
            <Bar />
        );
    }
}

export default HelloWorldComponent;
```

En ES5 la función `React.createClass` se encarga que el valor de `this` sea el correcto en los métodos de tu componente, sin embargo `extends React.Component` no lo hace igual por lo que tienes dos opciones

1. Binding manual

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import Foo from './Foo'
   import Bar from './Bar'

   class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.metodo = this.metodo.bind(this);
       }

       metodo() {
           //haz algo con this
       }

       render() {
           return (
               <Foo />
               <Bar />
           );
       }
   }

   export default HelloWorldComponent;
   ```
2. Arrow functions

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import Foo from './Foo'
   import Bar from './Bar'

   class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
       }

       metodo = () => {
           //haz algo con this
       }

       render() {
           return (
               <Foo />
               <Bar />
           );
       }
   }

   export default HelloWorldComponent;
   ```

Puedes leer más sobre los dos tipos de componentes en [componentes simples e inteligentes](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) y más información sobre lo que debes tener en cuenta cuando uses [React y ES6](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus).

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma que tienes para crear un componente **stateless** o "sin estado" es la siguiente:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function HelloWorldComponent () {

  return ( <div className="message">Hello World! </div> )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Con ES6 debes de extender a `Component`. Tu ejemplo en ES6 es así:

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='message'>Hello world!!</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: algo que faltaria solo seria el export default HelloWorldComponent;